# SharePoint Apps - Failed pre-requisite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Having gone thru the process of installing Apps, I seem to be stuck with some sort of **missing pre-requisite** that I cant get my head around.

I have installed and configured App's, I can browse the App store and I can download one or two apps. For the majority of App's though they are all greyed out. When I click on them I see a message saying

> "Sorry this App cannot be installed on your server"

When I look at the **ULS log**, I see an error for a failed pre-requisite when loading the add,

> Prerequisites Checking for App 'K2 blackpearl for SharePoint' failed: 
>   Service capability with name='Azure Access Control Service Application
>   Proxy' is not available. Service capability with name='Windows Azure
>   Active Directory Service Application Proxy or SharePoint Online
>   Application Principal Management Service Application Proxy' is not
>   available.
>
> Prerequisites Checking for App 'Actionspace for SharePoint & Office
>   365' failed:  Service capability with name='Azure Access Control
>   Service Application Proxy' is not available. Service capability with
>   name='Windows Azure Active Directory Service Application Proxy or
>   SharePoint Online Application Principal Management Service Application
>   Proxy' is not available.

Not really sure how "Azure Access Control" fits into it all, this is an **on-premise install of SharePoint 2013.** The error in ULS is the same regardless of the App.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this app from the Sharepoint App Store? If so i think there's a dependency on the version of the K2 Blackpearl Server.

Alternatively, have you tried uploading a full control K2 for Sharepoint app into your Sharepoint App Catalog?

http://help.k2.com/kb001443